# increase resolution by taking several pictures - is it done?

Tags: resolution, smartphone

What if I took two or more picture of the subject quickly one after another, then used these images to increase resolution?

It seems to me that if I take two pictures of the same thing, then my pixels will be aligned slightly differently with the image of an object. So it must be possible to process these images and achieve higher resolution than the camera's physical capabilities. Does anyone know of such software applications?

Comment: Interested to see if there's a "good" answer here.  It seems like you'd need at least three images; otherwise, you'd be equally likely to optimize the errors, wouldn't you?